# Initial load time is increasing by using preload strategy in Angular

Tags: angular, lazy-loading, preloading

I am using lazy loading in my application. But my featured module is taking time to load once I visit that route. So to reduce that load time, I am using Angular Preloading Strategy. But due to that initial load time of app is increased.

Ideally, the features module should load in the background and should not increase the initial load time.

For preloading, I add this code to my routing module.

```
RouterModule.forRoot(routes, {preloadingStrategy: PreloadAllModules})
```

What could be the issue?

Comment: Initial load time has increased, yes, but the time to interactivity is probably still the same as before.

Comment: By interactivity time, do you mean the user interaction time @wentjun? If that's correct, then no, render is blocked till all the compilation is done. The user is interacting once all the compilation is over.

Comment: I see.. Hmm, are you still facing this issue? I previously came across something similar to what you have faced, and I solved in by doing a custom loader strategy after reading some blog on the internet. I can paste the link on my next comment, if you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. This is how pre-loading strategy works in Angular. Whenever any module is pre-loaded, it loads in background after loading all eagerly loaded and required lazily loaded modules. After that pre-loading of modules starts. As all pre-loaded modules are first compiled and loaded in case of normal build and dev build (non aot build), which increases load time of current module.

But in aot build this issue will not occur as most time is utilised in compiling the module which will be skipped in aot build.

Comment: Yes, @Khush. When I run the aot build in the server I realized this. It won't feel like any new bundle is getting loaded. Forgot to update here. Thanks for writing it down. Marking it accepted.

Answer (score 0):

Even I have same issue, I solved this by removing preloadingStrategy, insted of that
I keep loader on route change at app.component. ts,

So user at least know that it's taking some time to load data

```
isLoading : boolean = false;

this.router.events.subscribe((event: Event) => {
   switch(true) {
     case event instanceof NavigationStart: {
       this.isLoading = true;
       break;
     }

     case event instanceof NavigationCancel:
     case event instanceof NavigationError:
     case event instanceof NavigationEnd: {
      this.isLoading = false;
      break;
    }
     default: {

      }
   }
 })
```

- ............Loading...........

Comment: For me, that load time is close to 10 seconds. I don't think holding the user on that loading screen for 10 seconds is a good idea. In all documentation, it says that preloading will load the bundle in background w/o interfering the main bundle. I don't know, what's going wrong here.

Answer (score 0):

I've created a short video explanation of how to create Custom Preloading Strategy - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tDQc3CCvKfc

and here is the code - https://github.com/stevermeister/AngularPro-Screencast/tree/master/code/Season4-Router-Features/preloading